# Access Android resources sqlite database .db inside the app

Tags: android, sqlite

my android app is calling a native c++ function which works fine using a .so library.

> "openDatabase(String path)"

The path is the sqlite database .db but i have no idea how to get this file inside my android compiled app. Right now it is located in resources folder but how can i access it inside my app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to copy the database to the phone in order for it to work BUT you also have to initialize the database with the SQLite function in order to use it with the c++ native function.

Answer (score 0):

Resources are not files on the device. They are files on the development machine. You would need to copy the resource to a file, then use the file.

Comment: Hey, i just did this : http://www.javahelps.com/2015/04/import-and-use-external-database-in.html and i used this to get the path : HelloWorldApp.this.getDatabasePath("database.db").toString(); which gave me this : /data/user/0/com.ht.android.hello_world_android/databases/database.db but still on my native side, it cannot find it

Comment: @hugo411: Perhaps the database does not exist yet. Calling `getDatabasePath()` does not create a database. When you use the Device File Explorer in Android Studio, do you see the database?

Comment: damn youre right, it's not there. But it should and the compiling take a lot of time (the database is 250mb)